# I cannot convert myISAM to innodb

Tags: mysql, database, innodb, myisam

I did a wipe and restore.

1. I backedup my current innodb tables.  (mysqldump)
2. I loaded it into the database.
3. For some reason...the tables are now all myisam instead of innodb...weird!
4. I try to do:

   ALTER TABLE xxx ENGINE=innodb;

And it doesn't do anything to any table.

"Show table status" still is "MyISAM"

```
mysql> alter table auth_user_user_permissions engine=innodb;
Query OK, 0 rows affected, 1 warning (0.06 sec)
Records: 0  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0



+------------+----------+----------------------------------------------------------------+
| Engine     | Support  | Comment                                                        |
+------------+----------+----------------------------------------------------------------+
| MyISAM     | DEFAULT  | Default engine as of MySQL 3.23 with great performance         |
| MEMORY     | YES      | Hash based, stored in memory, useful for temporary tables      |
| InnoDB     | DISABLED | Supports transactions, row-level locking, and foreign keys     |
| BerkeleyDB | NO       | Supports transactions and page-level locking                   |
| BLACKHOLE  | YES      | /dev/null storage engine (anything you write to it disappears) |
| EXAMPLE    | NO       | Example storage engine                                         |
| ARCHIVE    | YES      | Archive storage engine                                         |
| CSV        | YES      | CSV storage engine                                             |
| ndbcluster | DISABLED | Clustered, fault-tolerant, memory-based tables                 |
| FEDERATED  | DISABLED | Federated MySQL storage engine                                 |
| MRG_MYISAM | YES      | Collection of identical MyISAM tables                          |
| ISAM       | NO       | Obsolete storage engine                                        |
+------------+----------+----------------------------------------------------------------+



# * InnoDB
#
# InnoDB is enabled by default with a 10MB datafile in /var/lib/mysql/.
# Read the manual for more InnoDB related options. There are many!
# You might want to disable InnoDB to shrink the mysqld process by circa 100MB.
#skip-innodb

innodb_buffer_pool_size = 10000M
innodb_additional_mem_pool_size = 20M
innodb_log_file_size=1024M
innodb_log_buffer_size=8M
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit = 0


mysql> alter table auth_group engine=innodb;
Query OK, 0 rows affected, 1 warning (0.05 sec)
Records: 0  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> show warnings;
+---------+------+----------------------------------------------------+
| Level   | Code | Message                                            |
+---------+------+----------------------------------------------------+
| Warning | 1266 | Using storage engine MyISAM for table 'auth_group' |
+---------+------+----------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: This is a longshot, but is it possible that your new install of MySQL doesn't include InnoDB support? To see the supported engines issue the following query: `show engines;`. What is the output?

Comment: I see you've included an update showing that there is a warning. What is the output of the following query: `show warnings;`?

Comment: Very old versions of MySQL do not have InnoDB enabled by default. What version of MySQL are you using? What is the output of the following query: `select version();`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I see in your `show engines` output that InnoDB is disabled in your MySQL install. You need to enable it in order to be able to convert your tables from MyISAM to InnoDB.

Comment: @alex: What version of MySQL are you using? Check with `select version();`.

Comment: @alex: Are there any entries in the MySQL error log (during startup, perhaps) that appear to be related to InnoDB support?

Comment: I got it. Remove ib_logfile0 and ib_logfile1.